# Nothing shows up in rviz when following the SLAM Map Building Tutorial

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the
[SLAM Map Building with TurtleBot Tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM),
all I get is this:
[image description http://web.mit.edu/atmiguel/www/Screenshot-1.png](http://web.mit.edu/atmiguel/www/Screenshot-1.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36899/nothing-shows-up-in-rviz-when-following-the-slam-map-building-tutorial/) by [atmiguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2640/atmiguel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Just toggle the "Views" tab on the right side menu to all the options (Orbit, XYOrbit, FPS, TopDownOrtho) and you will get the view. I guess this is a bug. Only when you toggle between options the visualizer gets refreshed to show the map and grids.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1